# R package - @example function can't be tested if the function is not exported

Tags: r

I'm developping a custom R package with RStudio, documented with roxygen2.

Please consider this function:

```
#' Get "test"
#'
#' @return String
#' @export
#'
#' @examples getTest()
getTest <- function() {
  return("test")
}
```

If I run a `R CMD check` with the function documentation written as above, everything is fine, the `check` is passed with success.

Now, if I remove the `@export` (because I don't want this function to be visible from outside the package), I get the following error:

```
* checking examples ... ERROR
Running examples in 'MyPackageName-Ex.R' failed
The error most likely occurred in:

> ### Name: getTest
> ### Title: Get "test"
> ### Aliases: getTest
> 
> ### ** Examples
> 
> getTest()
Error: could not find function "getTest"
Execution halted
```

It looks like the test of the functions in `@examples` is run from outside the package!?

**How do I test the examples of non-exported function?**

Comment: Examples are part of the documentation. And documentation is for exported functions only. If your goal is unit testing use one of the packages implementing that, e.g., if you want to stay in the hadleyverse, package testthat.

Comment: You said: "documentation is for exported functions only". Is it a R philosophy? Or a Roxygen2 philosophy? Because I want to document these non-exported function as well, at least for me or the co-developper of my package. And add some examples for a better understanding! One solution could be to unit test with testthat, and add the examples in `dontrun{}` blocks. It is not that satisfying, though..

Comment: You should reread "Writing R Extensions". I simply use comments to document unexported functions for myself.

Comment: @Ronald Which section?

Answer (score 12):

I respectfully disagree with @Roland's comment, in that having an example proximal to the documentation is helpful to know what the heck I was thinking 6 months down the road.  Having it checked automatically with `check()` means it has a fighting chance to stay synced with the code.  I have not seen any prohibition or exhortation in the R docs against documenting non-exported functions.

Thankfully, you can call the unexported function with the triple-colon `:::` operator.  Example:

```
 ##' Drop specified dimension from an array
 ##'
 ##' Like drop(x) but only dropping specified dimensions.
 ##' There is no testing that the specified dimensions are actually     singletons.
 ##' @param x array of at least d dimensions
 ##' @param d dimension(s) to drop
 ##' @return array x
 ##' @examples
 ##' x = array(1:4, dim=c(1, 2, 1, 2))
 ##' dx = MAST:::Drop(x, 1)
 ##' stopifnot(all(dim(dx)==c(2,1,2)))
 ##' 
    Drop <- function(x, d){
        dim(x) <- dim(x)[-d]
        x
    }
```

Comment: Agreed - documentation is as much for myself and co-developers as it is for end users.

Comment: Unfortunately I've had a package rejected from CRAN due to `:::` in an example section of a non-exported function. If anyone has a CRAN-compatible solution it would be well worth a second answer!!